# Mvvmcross 8.0.2 Android MvxDialogFragment not close with back button

Tags: android, mvvmcross

After upgraded Mvvmcross from 7.1.2 to 8.0.2, I found the Dialog can no longer be closed with the back button. I verified that it behaves the same in Playground "Show Modal" (7.1.2 can close, 8.0.2 not). Is that done on purpose or a bug in the upgrade?

I tried to catch the back button event but none of them works:

```
public override void OnCancel(IDialogInterface dialog)
public override void DismissAllowingStateLoss()
public override void Dismiss()
public override void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
```

Any code changes is required in 8.0.2, or workaround available to close the dialog fragment on back button click?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug. You now need to add `[MvxDialogFragmentPresentation(Cancelable = true)]` to enable closing a dialog with the back button. The documentation states Cancelable should [default to true](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/android/android-view-presenter#mvxdialogfragmentpresentationattribute).